# express and jade: loop and create dynamic ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

Ok, this should be a simple question on node.

Using express, one has one document called app.js, another one index.jade, one more index.js, and typically another javascript, say server.js, where the bulk of the work for the server is done (the code here can be inside app.js, but let's say that these are different files).

Say I have two object like these

```
myIDs   = ['afoo', 'abar'];
myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

in the server.js and I would like to iterate through their elements in jade, and create buttons that have the value foo and bar respectively and their ids are afoo and abar respectively. How can we do such a thing?

Moreover, is it possible to realize if a mouse click occurs in one of these buttons? I tried to give a name to a specific button I created dynamically by using something like this

```
html = "<button id=\"aUniqueID\">Press me!</button>"
document.getElementById('puff').innerHTML = html;
```

but, even though it appears in the browser, nothing happens when the button is pressed (I am sending a message to the server, and the server is supposed to print a console log).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you don't use an inline function and I would attach the click event on the client-side but you can add it inline just like normal with jade

This assumes that the value and id for each button are at the same array position:

```
myIDs   = ['afoo', 'abar'];
myArray = ['foo', 'bar'];

each button_id, i in myIDs
    button(id="#{button_id}", onclick="yourFunctionHere();") #{myArray[i]}
```

UPDATED:

To pass the arrays to the .jade page is like:

```
app.get('/your-url-path', function(req, res){

    var my_ids_array = ['afoo', 'abar'];
    var my_values_array = ['foo', 'bar'];

    res.render('your-jade-page', { myIDs: my_ids_array, myArray: my_values_array });
});
```

Comment: Thank you drivativ. I am accepting it, but I guess my problem is more fundamental because I have no clue how to pass the variables to index.jade.

Comment: Okay, so probably in server.js you render the page like: res.render('your-jade-page', {myIDs: [your-array], myArray: [you-array]}), so you just generate those arrays and pass them as object attributes in the second parameter of res.render

Comment: I believe that you are right with this approach. However, the way express generates the template, this res.render(...) command is in itself in another file under the directory routes. So, it is a little bit chaotic. In app.js we have a statement like: app.get('/', routes.index); , this index function is exported from the file routes/index.js, the server.js script is loading socket.io and exporting an initialization function that does  io = io.listen(server); io.sockets.on("connection", handleConnection);
and finally in app.js once the server is created, this initialization function is called

Comment: with a statement of the form require('./routes/server.js').initialize(server);
where 'server' is the variable that was initialized with a statement like http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){});